# Avoid @ngrx/effects to cancel same actions

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Is there a way to avoid effects to cancel previous one ?

I need to do:

```
this.tagsStoreService.initTagsForFamilyId(this.tagFamily.id)
```

I have this effects:

```
@Effect() initTagsForFamilyId$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType<InitTagsForFamilyIdAction>(TagsStateActionTypes.INIT_TAGS_FOR_FAMILY_ID_ACTION),
        switchMap(params => {
            // this.loadingService.showLoading();
            return this.tagsService.initTagsForFamilyId(params.payload)
                .pipe(
                    exhaustMap((data) => {
                        this.loadingService.hideLoading();

                        return [
                            new InitTagsForFamilyIdSuccessAction({ ...data }),
                        ];
                    }),
                    catchError(error => {
                        // this.loadingService.hideLoading();
                        return of(new TagsFailureAction({ error }));
                    }),
                );
        }),
    );
```

Thanks in advance for help ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `mergeMap` instead `switchMap`

```js
let {
  interval,
  of
} = rxjs
let {
take,
tap,
switchMap,
delay,
finalize
} = rxjs.operators

const switchMapCase = interval(500).pipe(
  take(5),
  tap(() => console.log("new request")),
  switchMap(() =>
    of(null).pipe(
      delay(800),
      tap(() => console.log("end")),
      finalize(() => console.log("request stream complete"))
    )
  )
);

switchMapCase.subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

If you run the snippet above (the one with `switchMap`) you will notice that every `500` ms a new event is emitted (new request), this event will go inside the `switchMap` and return a new observable that will be resolved after `800` ms , because `800` > `500` before the inner observable is resolved new observable will come from the source stream, which will cancel the current inner stream (the one with `800` ms delay) and a new stream that also has `800` ms delay will be returned.
This thing will happen 5 times (because of the `take(5)` operator, this is equivalent to dispatching the `TagsStateActionTypes.INIT_TAGS_FOR_FAMILY_ID_ACTION` action 5 times, with `500` ms delay between each dispathc). In the 5-th iteration the inner observable will complete, as there will be no new dispatches that will cancel it.

```js
let {
  interval,
  of
} = rxjs
let {
take,
tap,
mergeMap,
delay,
finalize
} = rxjs.operators

const mergeMapCase = interval(500).pipe(
  take(5),
  tap(() => console.log("new request")),
  mergeMap(() =>
    of(null).pipe(
      delay(800),
      tap(() => console.log("server response recieved")),
      finalize(() => console.log("request stream complete"))
    )
  )
);

mergeMapCase.subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

In the snippet above (the `mergeMap`) we have pretty much we have the same structure with the only difference that we use `mergeMap` instead `switchMap` the difference will be that unlike `switchMap` (that cancels the previous stream) `mergeMap` will add the new "innerStream" to the source observable without canceling the old ones.

*Side Note: *
The thing that actually is getting canceled in the effects is not the `action` or the `effect` it is the `this.tagsService.initTagsForFamilyId` observable, that on completion will trigger another another `action`.